# Inheritance and overload for simple types

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

Why does this [snippet](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/559828ada43c80b6) compile (and prints "Fi Fi"):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f(int) { cout << "Fi" << endl; }
void f(float) { cout << "Ff" << endl; }

struct A
{
   void f(int) { cout << "Fi" << endl; }
   void f(float) { cout << "Ff" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  f(0);
  A().f(0);
}
```

but [this one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb78e28c374e8570) doesn't?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A { void f(int) { cout << "Fi" << endl; } };
struct B { void f(float) { cout << "Ff" << endl; } };

struct C : A, B
{};

int main()
{
   C().f(0); // (1)
}
```

In my understanding, line (1) should call `A::f`, but the call is ambiguous instead.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find it right now. I closed a similar question just a few days ago.

Comment: What compiler / version are you using (in case it is compiler specific)

Comment: @pmr I've found other similar question, but always related to virtual functions and so on, and not regular overloads.

Comment: The duplicate is exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @Soren The same as the one given by coliru (check the links).

Comment: It's because name lookup (that happens before overload resolution) is ambiguous - it finds name `f` in two different base classes.

Comment: Note that the error will be the same if you, for example, change `B:foo` to be data member instead of function.